# MySQL: Select rank from grouped result

Tags: php, mysql

I have a table which contains data from a radio station, and which songs it played. All the songs played are stored in a table named 'radio_data'. This table looks like this:

```
-----------------------------------------------
| id | artist_id | song_id | play_date        |
| 1    230         420       2017-5-12 12:00  |
| 2    212         971       2017-5-12 12:01  |
| 3    230         420       2017-5-12 13:00  |
| 4    230         420       2017-5-12 15:00  |
| 5    212         971       2017-5-12 15:02  |
-----------------------------------------------
```

I have a page where some statistics for one specific song is displayed. On this page i would like to show the rank of the song, based on how much it has been played.

Let's say that if i am om the page for song_id 420, it would rank as place 1 out of 2 songs.
I have no idea where to start. I have this query to group the songs:

```
SELECT COUNT(`id`) AS `playcount`, `artist_id`, `song_id` FROM `radio_data` GROUP BY `song_id` ORDER BY `playcount` DESC
```

This gives me the following result:

```
-----------------------------------
| playcount | artist_id | song_id |
|  3           230         420    |
|  2           212         971    |
-----------------------------------
```

Thanks in advance for your help!

Comment: And what is the desired result set?

Comment: Please check the query you claim works, as it has an obvious error in it

Comment: A set with the rank for 1 specific song_id. So if i want to see the results for song_id 420, i would see that it is on place 1, becuase it is played more than song_id 971.

Comment: See: [Why should I provide an MCVE for what seems to me to be a very simple SQL query?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/333952/why-should-i-provide-an-mcve-for-what-seems-to-me-to-be-a-very-simple-sql-query)

Comment: @RiggsFolly fixed the query

Comment: Do you need a rank column in the result too ? `1,2,3,4`

Comment: Since your query result will be in order when using PHP to fetch, you can just use array index of PHP as the ranking. It makes thing simpler.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use user variables for displaying the rank:

```
set @rn := 0;

select @rn := @rn + 1 as rank,
    song_id,
    artist_id,
    count(*) as times_played
from your_table
group by song_id, artist_id
order by times_played desc;
```

If you want to get top, say 10, songs you can add a `limit 10` at the end.

Comment: Nice one! Working like a charm. Thanks!

Comment: @jVr - Glad it helped. :)

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT
    song_id, count(id) played_times, @rank := @rank +1 rank
FROM
    (
      songs_plays CROSS JOIN (SELECT @rank := 0)rank
    )

GROUP BY song_id
ORDER BY played_times DESC
```

the result is

```
+------------+--------------+--------+
| song_id    | played_times | rank   |
+------------+--------------+--------+
|   420      |       3      |   1    |
|   971      |       2      |   2    |
+------------+--------------+--------+
```

run it live on SQL fiddle (http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/1c48d8/5)

Comment: Works great! Thanks for your help!